# IDA pseudocode support

Tags: ida, decompilation, hexrays

How can I know which processors IDA knows how to view pseudocode of?

If IDA does not know to view pseudocode for my processor, how can I fix that??

Answer (score 3):

- Decompilation is done by another product of Hex-Rays, which is called Hex-Rays Decompiler. You can find more about it [here](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/decompiler/index.shtml).
- The page includes the list of supported processors (correct for December 2019):

  > x86, x64, ARM32, ARM64, PowerPC, and PowerPC64
- This product is implemented as a plugin for IDA, doesn't work without IDA itself, has its own license,and cost additional money.
- If you processor is not supported by Hex-Rays Decompiler, you can either use [Ghidra](https://www.nsa.gov/resources/everyone/ghidra/) instead of IDA (it has common, but less polished decompiler for all processors it supports) or find/create decompiler plugin yourself.